# [Solved](rosjava)catkin_create_rosjava_pkg: command not found

Tags: raspberrypi, ros-kinetic, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava_build_tools/Tutorials/indigo/Creating%20Rosjava%20Packages

I tried this.

> ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ mkdir -p src<br>
> ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ cd src
> ubuntu@ubuntu:~/src$ catkin_create_rosjava_pkg rosjava_catkin_package_a
> catkin_create_rosjava_pkg: command not found

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277437/%5Bsolved%5D(rosjava)catkin_create_rosjava_pkg:-command-not-found/) by [ramekabi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32877/ramekabi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you source rosjava_build_tools before running that?

If you followed the instructions to install rosjava from source (http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava/Tutorials/kinetic/Source%20Installation), you need to source the workspace:

```
source ~/rosjava/devel/setup.bash
```

Only after doing that you can start using those command line tools.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ramekabi](https://answers.ros.org/users/32877/ramekabi/) on 2017-12-06**:
Thank you. Solved.

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2017-12-06**:
Great!
Please mark the answer as the accepted one so others can make use of it.